# Аналог утилиты dir c++

Tags: c++, c

Не у кого нет аналога утилиты dir на С или C++?

Comment: `dir` в виндовом `cmd`? Это, кхм, не утилита, а внутренняя команда. У неё нет отдельного исполняемого файла, она реализована прямо в интерпретаторе команд.

Comment: Если в Linux, то см. [man 3 glob](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob), а вообще-то в подобных вопросах указывайте ОС.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @D-side я же написал что мне нужен её аналог на c++. я знаю что это команда cmd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

И для Win и для Lin можно использовать один код для показа содержимого директории:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> //только для Lin
#include <dirent.h>

int main()
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    dir = opendir("/");
    if (!dir) {
        perror("diropen");
        return 1;
    };

    while ( (entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
    };

    closedir(dir);
    return 0;
};
```

Файл `dirent.h` адаптированный под Win легко находится на просторах интернета, например, [**здесь**](https://github.com/tronkko/dirent/blob/master/include/dirent.h) или [**здесь**](https://github.com/gameclosure/gcif/blob/master/msvc/dirent.h) и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

В библиотеке `Qt` имеется класс `QDir`, обладающий нужным вам функционалом.

Answer (score 1):

Раз перечисляют все варианты: [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), а там то, что [вам нужно](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html#Directory-iteration)

Библиотека Filesystem, если не ошибаюсь, будет в C++17.